# Application.js more than 1 Mb rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a rails application and the `application.js` after asset compilation takes more than 1 MB. This is slowing down my entire site.

I use Apache, Rails 4, jQuery, quite heavy JavaScript and AJAX. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Akarienta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This may not be feasible in your particular case, but has certainly helped me keep Application.js from bloating.*

As I'm sure you know, Application.js compiles all specified files (by default, all of them) into a single .js file, which is loaded (again, by default) as part of your layout in every page. Often times this results in the inclusion of entirely unnecessary custom scripts loading in every page, and slowing down the entire application. I personally find this behavior undesirable. What I find works for my sites is only including my "core" javascript components in Application.js (jquery, bootstrap's js libraries, and any scripts that pertain to layout.html.erb itself), and specifying the rest in the pages that need them. For example:

### application.js

Note that it does NOT include `require tree .`. This is important, as that is the line which specifies the inclusion of the entire assets/javascripts folder. "Template" in this case is the .js file a defined which pertains to layout.html.erb

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require template
//= require turbolinks
```

### layout.html.erb

The following is the very end of my layout, immediately before the closing body tag. This loads application.js on every page, and after that loads any js specified in the view.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<% if content_for?(:javascript) %>
    <%= yield :javascript%>
<% end %>
```

### The View(s)

In any view that requires page-specific javascript, you may specify the files with a Rails javascript helper

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'pages/profile', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<% end %>
```

### initializers/assets.rb

Finally, make sure that your scripts are still being precompiled, even though they aren't a part of Application.js.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages/profile.js )
```

...or, more efficiently assuming you have many pages with their own scripts...

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages/* )
```

### In Conclusion

I find this  technique really helps keep the size of Application.js down, and makes for good practice in general. I hope you find it useful, and apologize if it is extraneous to your problem.

Comment: Hi Connor, 

Many thanks for such an elaborate response. What you have suggested could be quite relevant in my case. I will optimise my application.js file based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever thought about using the CDN hosted jQuery Version? Could you provide your uncompiled application.js.

You could also try to use [browserify](http://browserify.org) or [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)